# Data Structure Question: Is there a link between the size of a list in a chaining implementation of hash maps and its load factor?

Tags: hashmap

For example, if I have n keys and m slots in the hash map, the average size of a linked list starting from a slot would be n/m. Am I correct in thinking this? Again, I'm talking about an average. Thanks in advance!

I'm trying to learn data structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, the *average* size of a single list is generally going to be the table's load factor; but this is assuming that the ["Simple Uniform Hashing Assumption"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUHA_%28computer_science%29) holds with your hash table (more specifically, with its hash function(s) and expected input keys): simply put, we assume that the hash function distributes elements to buckets uniformly, as well as independently of one another.

To expand a little, and in different words:
We assume that if we choose a new item randomly (imagine sampling an item from the probability distribution that characterizes our inputs), then there is an equal chance that the item we end up with will be mapped to any of the m buckets. (A chance of 1/m.)
Furthermore, that this probability is unaffected given the presence (or absence) of any other elements in any of the buckets.
This is helpful because from this we can conclude that the probability for an item to be sorted into a given bucket is always 1/m, regardless of any other circumstances; from this it directly follows that the expected (average) length of a single bucket's list will be n/m (we insert n elements into the table, and for each one, sort it into this given list at a probability of 1/m).

To see that this is important, we might imagine a case in which it doesn't hold: for instance, if we're facing some kind of "attack" and our inputs are engineered to all hash into the same bucket, or even just with a high probability. In this case SUHA no longer holds, and clearly neither does the link you've asked about between the length of a list and the load factor.

This is part of the reason that it is important to choose a good hash function for your use case: without it, the assumption may not hold which could have a harmful effect on your lookup times.